# Read and Manipulate Volume Settings for Specific Programs

Tags: java, audio, controls, volume, javasound

I'm using Java to work with Windows 7, and I'm trying to read the levels of sound output from different programs.

The goal is to detect when program A is playing sound, lower program's B sound, and when program A no longer has sound playing, program B will return to normal volume.

Is there a library that will allow me to read the data and then manipulate the volume levels?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Java Sound be used to control the system volume?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume)

Comment: no, this is not possible in java.

Comment: Is there any language in which this is possible?