# accessing volume controls of computer through java

Tags: java, api

Is there any API in java to access hardware resources like volume controls?
i want to access volume controls of my laptop using java.i have tried java media framework to access controls but it is giving only basic information.

Comment: Have you seen this? Might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume

Comment: thanks for your suggestion . i have tried that but i want to increase or decrease volume programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at Oracle's Java SOund API
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html

Comment: any small piece  of code or any example?

Comment: Its available here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html

Comment: Thanks i have solved this by using applets and executing in browser...