# JAVA + change OS default audio output

Tags: java, operating-system, javasound

I'm pretty sure of having read in some place about the impossibility of Java source application in JavaSE platform, to change the OS' default audio output configuration. More explained, I need to check a reference of some official documentation where stands this allowed or denied. Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: The Java Sound API simply does not provide anything that can be used to do this.

Comment: Where can I find an official reference to that? Please I need the official documentation because I'm designing a proposal for Audio Routing and I need to justify the existing options.

Comment: The only official reference I know of besides the API is the audio tutorial track. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

Comment: @PhilFreihofner *"the API"* I'd argue that the API, and its complete lack of reference to doing any such thing, should be enough. I was involved with a question related to [changing the system volume](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume/14301620#14301620) & Java Sound is **not** capable of doing that. There is also the general principle that Java (in general) does not allow close access to the hardware of the machine, and it would be necessary to have that level of access in order to achieve the stated goal. Doubt it's explicitly ..

Comment: .. stated in regard to Java Sound in any official documentation. Mostly because it should be understood as 'a given'. Note for the OP: This info. is coming to you from the [top ranked](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/topusers) provider of answers in Java Sound (me) in reply to the person who actually knows more about it & audio processing in general (Phil).

Comment: So @AndrewThompson, then can I conclude that there's no such thing as a reference into the API documentation about this topic in any where? I've read everything you pointed at in your comments before and, I wasn't able to find anything related to this. Anyways I don't know if maybe I'm missing something in another article or API reference. Until now I still looking for it. Grettings.

Comment: *"there's no such thing as a reference .. about this topic in any where"* Short answer, no. Long answer, nope.

Answer (score 0):

My only suggestion would to use JNI, which would writing a c++ shared object that java can interface with. Or have the a java process run powershell to change it.