# How Can I Record Microphone And Speakers Audio at Same Time in Java?

Tags: java, javasound

How to get audio from microphone (Line-In) and playback device (speakers Line-Out) in Java?

Comment: You ***might*** be able to get the 'playback' sound using Java Sound (tag added). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14301618/can-java-sound-be-used-to-control-the-system-volume/14301620#14301620) for a start on looking into the sound system.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank for your help.
But my computer (windows) mixer name: Java Sound Audio Engine not showed.

Comment: Well, that Q&A was specifically about ***changing the system volume.*** I directed your attention to it, as it lists **all** the sound lines. Try tapping into some of the others.

Comment: @AndrewThompson my computer have not Java sound, so i can't get sound of playback?

Comment: *"my computer have not Java sound"* If it has the J2SE, is has the Java Sound API.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thank for you help!
I think j2se is installed in my computer. It have 6 mixer but have not Java Sound.
Do you give a suggestion ?

Comment: Well, I said this a couple of comments ago, but I'll repeat it more *emphatically* and **boldly.** ***Try tapping into some of the others.*** Do you get the sound signal you need from any of *them?* (I don't understand your obsession with the Java Sound Engine that was only mentioned in passing!)

Comment: BTW - the answer form below is **not** for extra information. Instead [edit] the question to add new information.